# Why Activity.findViewById result type is inferred as a platform type?

Tags: android, kotlin, type-inference

I'm new to Android development and Kotlin.

I'm following the first Android tutorial with Kotlin and I have this method call:

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
```

Where `findViewById` is defined in `android.app.Activity` as:

```
@Nullable
public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id)
```

Android Studio shows me that `editText` is inferred as being of type `EditText!`. I read Kotlin documentation about Java interoperability and platform types, but since `findViewById` is annotated with `android.annotation.Nullable`, which is ([according to Kotlin documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations)) among the list of supported nullability annotations, I would have expected `editText` type to be inferred as `EditText?`.

I see that the desired result is obtained if I change my code to:

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText?>(R.id.editText)
```

But why is this needed and `@Nullable` simply ignored?

Comment: The method is nullable, not the class specification. I'm pretty sure Kotlin internally casts `findViewById` to what's in the brackets.

Comment: Did you type in the `EditText` in `findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)` yourself? Or was this auto-completed by the IDE?

Comment: @CommonsWare does it make any difference?

Comment: If you typed it in yourself, then you are the one saying that `findViewById()` is returning `EditText` instead of `EditText?`. Kotlin is not going to overrule you, as it assumes that you know what you are doing. If, instead, you got it from a tool, then perhaps that tool has a bug, where it should be paying attention to that `@Nullable` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The method may be nullable, but your class specification isn't. I've decompiled one of my APKs and found the following.

Here's a simple Kotlin method:

```
private fun setAppName() {
    val name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.app_name)
    name.text = appInfo.appName
}
```

You can see the specification of `name` as being a TextView.

That method turns into the following when compiled:

```
private final void setAppName() {
    TextView textView = (TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(textView, "name");
    AppInfo appInfo = this.appInfo;
    if (appInfo == null) {
        Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("appInfo");
    }
    textView.setText(appInfo.getAppName());
}
```

Notice that it *casts* the return of `findViewById` to exactly what you put in the brackets. In your case, EditText.

Basically, that cast messes everything up. It would be similar to doing this:

```
val view: View? = findViewById(R.id.whatever)
val castView: TextView = view as TextView
```

It effectively bypasses the `@Nullable` because of how Kotlin handles type inference.

Comment: There's no concept of "[non-]nullable" class in Java. It's clear what Kotlin is doing, but I don't understand why. If you have `@Nullable String foo() { ... }` method in Java and you call that method from Kotlin, the inferred type is `String?`, not `String!`, that's the purpose of nullability annotations.

Comment: Because the nullability is on the method. Take a look at what Kotlin becomes when it's compiled. You have `findViewById()` which returns a nullable receiver, but then you cast it to a non-null TextView. IDE lint isn't that smart. It can only point out potential issues through 1 or 2 levels at most.

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. Here we have `@Nullable public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id)`, so the nullability is declared on the method as well. `<EditText>` should be a type capturing hint, not a cast...

Comment: Look at the Java code I posted. Kotlin compiles to Java bytecode and adds its own null-check helper methods during compilation. You can see very clearly that `findViewById<EditText>()` is simply `(EditText) findViewById()`. Since you don't use `EditText?`, Kotlin doesn't add a null-check method in.

Comment: So, do we agree it's a Kotlin compiler bug? The result type of `findViewById` is `T?`, whatever `T` is. With `<EditText>` I'm saying `T` is `EditText`, so I expect it to return `EditText?`. If instead we say that `<EditText>` is expressing a cast, then the result should be of type `EditText` and not `EditText!`. Right now, Kotlin is simply replacing `T` with `EditText` and ignoring the `@Nullable` annotation.

Comment: @MauroMolinari it's not a bug. It's just how Kotlin works. Feel free to report it if you want though.

Comment: Reported as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27566, the problem is that those annotations by Google have source retention and hence are not available in the bytecode for the Kotlin compiler to process them.

Answer (score 0):

The actual annotation set on `android.app.Activity` is `@android.annotation.Nullable`. The non-nullable counterpart is `@android.annotation.NonNull`. These are not among the "Android nullability annotations" currently supported by Kotlin ([see documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations)), which are rather declared in packages `com.android.annotations` and `android.support.annotations`.

I opened issue [KT-27566](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27566) and emerged that these annotations are currently ignored because they have source retention, and hence they are not available in the compiled bytecode for Kotlin compiler processing.

Moreover, according to [KT-25279](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25279), it seems like that there are other such annotations, defined instead in package `com.android.support`, which suffer from the same problem.

I really don't understand why Google is doing such a mess with nullability annotations (so many different variants, some of them that are useless for Kotlin integration, where their usefulness would be maximum instead...).